# Can't create ext4 partition while installing ubuntuGnome 15.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 15.04, ext4

I tried to install ubuntu Gnome 15.04 on a Sony Vaio laptop currently running openSuse 13.2. The iso's md5 checked out and the usb booted all right, but when I select delete current Os and install it says it can't create ext4 partition. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I took a look at it with disks it recognizes the previous system partition as swap. Currently disks shows:
536MB efi
4.2GB Swap
123GB Swap

Comment: I tried to delete the 123gb partition with disks  but it throws an error message that it is busy. Could it be something with grub form the previous install? Should I try to delete the efi and all partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used before openSuse, maybe format the PC with a windows disc and install the OS, or try using Gparted using a Ubuntu 12.04 install disc and give it the Ext4 Format.<-------------i recommend that option also make a backup because it could fail and make you loss the data stored in the PC.

Btw srry for the bad english.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks you put me into the right direction, but since I did not need to do a backup I was able to solve the problem using the installer's default partitioning tool.

Comment: Maybe the HDD is protected in the Bios,you can check the BIOS to see if there's any kind of protection. or if you are happy with the installation you did then congrats :D ask if there's any doubt.

Comment: No there is no protection in the bios. It seems it must be some unknown messup, maybe grub frome the openSUSE install or something with Disks as on the first (automatic)try it threw an error saying it could not format the ext4 partition but after that all data was deleted and it somehow came to be marked as swap and got remounted and therefore could not be deleted. If I find the reason I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

I booted into live mode, used Disks to disable automounting the partition recognized wrongly recognized as swap (sda2, 123 GB) removed the efi partition and rebooted into the installer. 
Now I still could not remove or format partitions, but I was able to create a new partition table manually and successfully install and boot into ubuntuGnome 15.04.